# EmberJS: Update multiple models on save

Tags: javascript, ember.js, parse-platform

Looking for some advice on the best way to update multiple models on save. Why might I want to do this, you ask? Well, I'm using [Parse](https://parse.com/) as my backend and unfortunately relationships are only one way. In order for them to work in Ember, I need to manually manage pointers.

**Example:** Obj A belongs to Obj B. Obj B has many Obj As. Parse stores a pointer from Obj B to Obj A, but I need to store an array of objects in Obj B that contains IDs for all of the Obj As. When I go to delete an Obj A, I need to save Obj B with the updated array of As. Currently, I'm doing something like this in my component logic:

```
ObjA.save().then(() => {
  ObjB.save();
});
```

That seems to work, but I'd like to move this logic to the adapter so I don't have to think about it every time I'm deleting (or adding) a new object.

I was thinking I could find a hook somewhere in the adapter to check if if an object is being deleted. If so, send a `PUT` request to ObjB with the new list of ObjAs. I just need some guidance figuring out where that would go. Or, maybe the best way *is* to handle this in each component.

Answer (score 0):

There is [didDelete](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#event_didDelete) on model so you should be able to do it there. That said, api that does not have integrity check is head scratching.

Comment: I suppose that would work, but then I'd have to override on every model. I'd rather keep it within the adapter or serializer. If I want to turn it into an addon, that piece would be there since it's necessary for Parse relationships. I agree, though, the API decision is peculiar...

Comment: You can also reopen model class and do it all in one place.